# Error con ibm_db en Mac os High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, pip, ibm-bluemix

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con db2, hace poco cambie mi maquina linux por una Mac (debido a la empresa) y he tenido un problema que aún no puedo resolver. Por más que intento no puedo hacer correr el modulo **ibm_db** con python y me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya intenté instalando en python3 y tampoco, copie directamente la librería dentro del site-packages de python 2.7 y tampoco. Es la primer vez que uso Mac y estoy un poco enredado ¿Alguien me pudiera explicar que debo hacer?, muchas gracias!.

Comment: ¿Has Instalas la libreria con pip? No copies la libreria a site-packages, tiene partes escritas en C que han de ser compiladas para el sistema concreto.

Comment: Si, así es ya instale la librería con pip y en la consola después ejecuto el compilador de python e importo la librería y me dice el error que comento anteriormente.

Comment: He logrado resolver este problema con la siguiente variable de entorno:
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@2/libexec/bin:$PATH"


De cualquier forma, dejo el link de la web donde encontré la solución...
https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install/osx/